# colorscheme problems with terminal

Tags: vim

I am trying to install a custom colorscheme for vim

First I created the folders required

> mkdir -p ~/.vim/colors
>   cp wombat.vim  ~/.vim/colors        "wombat.vim being a colorscheme

Then I  added

> colorscheme wombat.vim

to .vimrc

Yet when I try load a vim file after the changes, I get message "E185: Cannot find color scheme wombat.vim".

Comment: Ask here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @BlackBear Questions about development tools are generally considered to be on topic here, though this one straddles the line a bit.  If anything, it might be best on superuser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to place your colorscheme files in:

`~/.vim/colors`

or:

`$HOME/.vim/colors`

for Vim to find them.

That's on OS X & Linux. I don't have a Windows box to test against.

Answer (score 4):

Just use

```
colorscheme wombat
```

...without the `.vim` on the end.

Inside vim, you can test this with

```
:colorscheme wombat
```

or use tab-completion after `:colorscheme` to cycle through your available colorschemes.

```
:colorscheme<Tab>
```

Comment: I tried that first, didn't work. When I tab through my colorscheme I can't find my "wombat" file so it may be in the wrong place.

Comment: @maxflow Did you already have a ~/.vim with other directories files & plugins?

Comment: no i do not have ~/.vim in any other directories, i also have no plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Add this [wombat.vim](http://files.werx.dk/wombat.vim) to ~/.vim/colors/wombat.vim